# Is the declaration of a variable name in a #define directive well defined?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variable-declaration

If I had the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VAR_NAME a_variable

int VAR_NAME = 42;

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", VAR_NAME);
    printf("%i\n", a_variable);
    a_variable = 123;
    printf("%i\n", VAR_NAME);
    printf("%i\n", a_variable);

    return 0;
}
```

Is the declaration of `a_variable` well defined? On my system, an `int` named `a_variable` is declared, but do I have to worry about alternate compilers declaring an `int` named `VAR_NAME`?

BTW, the above code outputs the following:

```
42
42
123
123
```

EDIT:

Furthermore, if the previous is well-defined, could I do the following?

```
#define VAR_NAME a_variable
...
#define DECL_VAR int VAR_NAME

// Declare an int named a_variable
DECL_VAR;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> do I have to worry about alternate compilers declaring an `int` named `VAR_NAME`?

No, you do not have to worry about that. Unless someone redefines `VAR_NAME` to something else, you will consistently get an `int` named `a_variable`.

`#define` directive is processed by preprocessor before the compiler gets to process the code. By the time the compiler "sees" your code, there is no `VAR_NAME` in there, only `a_variable` is left in all places where `VAR_NAME` has been used.

> Furthermore, if the previous is well-defined, could I do the following?
>
> ```
> #define DECL_VAR int VAR_NAME
> ```

Yes, as long as `VAR_NAME` is defined, this will work as well.

**Note:** The fact that it is well defined and standard-compliant does not mean that it is necessarily a good idea to use code like that, because cascaded declarations are difficult to read for human readers of your program.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the implementation complies with the standard, the preprocessor will perform text substitution, so every instance of `VAR_NAME` will be expanded to `a_variable`.

There are a couple of exceptions (e.g. macros inside string literals are not expanded).    But, if you use the macro in places where a variable name would normally be expected, the expansion will work as you expect.

It is also necessary to avoid reserved identifiers (identifiers that the standard reserves for use by the implementation - i.e. the compiler and standard headers).   For example, if you pick a name for your macro or for your variable that is reserved (e.g. that starts with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, such as `_VAR_NAME` rather than `VAR_NAME`) then the behaviour is undefined.

EDIT following edit of the original question:   Yes, the expansion of `DECL_VAR` works as you expect.

I would caution you against such things though.   Such tricks do not give many benefits, but can make your code harder to understand (after all, few people will know what `DECL_VAR;` will mean in your code unless they know you are playing with macros).   Code that is harder to understand is harder to get right.